# Solspace Calendar : Not able to retrieve previous events

Tags: solspace-calendar

I am trying to list 3 previous events but I'm not getting any results. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
{exp:calendar:events 
                            event_limit="3" 
                            status="open" 
                            date_range_end="today" 
                            show_weeks="10" 
                            orderby="event_start_date" 
                            sort="desc"
                            calendar_id="not 400|402"
                        }
                        <div class="col-xs-4 events-item">
                            <a href="{event_url_title}" class="image-block">
                                {event_images limit="1"}
                                <img src="{image:url:small}" alt="{event_title}">
                                {/event_images}
                            </a>
                            <div class="date">{event_start_date format="%M %j, %Y"} - {event_end_date format="%M %j, %Y"}</div>
                            <h3>{event_title}</h3>
                            <div class="description">
                                {event_snippet}
                            </div>
                            <a href="/events/{event_url_title}" class="blue">Read more</a>
                        </div><!-- /row events-item-->
                        {/exp:calendar:events}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're looking to display 3 previous events **based on a chronological timeline**, you need to use **`{exp:calendar:cal}`**, not `{exp:calendar:events}`. The reason has been explain many times here on EESE, the old Solspace support forums, as well as summarized on this documentation page: http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/getting_started/

Something like this is a good start:

```
{exp:calendar:cal 
   date_range_start="3 days ago" 
   date_range_end="today" 
   pad_short_weeks="n"
   limit="3"}
```

However, this will give you three events/occurrences *starting from 3 days ago*. I assume you want 3 events/occurrences *going back from today*. In that case, you might need to create a PHP array, and pick the last three items in the array. Those would be the events/occurrences closest to your date_range_end.